# Highcharts pointPlacement ignored in version 2.3.5

Tags: highcharts

It seems like in version 2.3.5 of the Highcharts library, the `pointPlacement` property on a column series is being ignored, even though according to the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column) the property has been in since version 2.3.0.

I have two Fiddles that show different behavior between [version 2.3.5](http://jsfiddle.net/markwrally/jB8gK/2/) and the [current verison](http://jsfiddle.net/kmckinney/L6f6G/).

Modifying the pointPlacement property has no apparent effect in the 2.3.5 version. Is this a bug, or is there some way of getting the same behavior in the older version? The Rally SDK uses version 2.3.5 of Highcharts, so I don't have an option to use the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pointPlacement`, where value can be number was added in 3.0.2 version.

See [changelog](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog).

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering it. I think that should be reflected in the documentation though, because without the ability to see the API for more than the most recent version, we have to rely on the 'Since x.y.z' label and in this case I think it's misleading. I'll be checking the changelog going forward if I run into more issues like that.

Comment: I agree that should be pointed in docs, I have already passed on that request to team responsible for docs :)